# SVN and Bug tracking

Tags: svn

I have post a question before about my company requirement and I have got a lot of answers and I have search a lot to get some information

**About SVN**

the option of CVS is very old and I'm not going to use it

I have also two type of SVN (Client Server and Distributed), we almost use **Distributed** in open source projects and if we are all working in the same project in the same place then we are going to use **Client Server SVN** so I think we are going to use Client Server Model

but I didn't find a lot of client server SVN Servers to install in my machine and let others to access it , I just found VisualSVN

so can any one tell me other examples of Client Server SVN servers that I can use , and also I want to know if it is easy to make one from scratch if i want to make one for my company

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What do you mean by "Client Server SVN"? do you just mean a SVN server? Or do you mean you want a visual frontend others can browse? (We use http://www.websvn.info/ for that)

Comment: I think you're confusing the general term ("version control system") with a specific implementation thereof ("SVN"). Try to clean this up, otherwise your question is almost incomprehensible.

Comment: What platform are you running?  Windows?  Linux?  And a version number would be nice as well.  I'm guessing you are running some flavor of Linux, but I could be wrong since you reference VisualSVN.

Comment: I'm working on Windows 7

Comment: Looks to be a duplicate post to this question from the same user now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658145/version-control-software-client-server-model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

umm, what's the relation w/ **Bug Tracking**?

have you tried Tortoise SVN or SmartSVN - they both are excellent clients. For the servers you can use [any of the Apache subversion server packages](http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html).

Comment: about bug tracking , I was planing to ask also about some thing related to bug tracking but I didn't , but any way I want the server of the SVN to also integrate with SVN , I have tried TortoiseSVN Client and i think it is very easy to use and I have tried it with VisualSVN server , I'm asking about other SVN servers that i can use instead of visualSVN