# Version Control software (client server model)

Tags: svn, apache, controls, version, visualsvn

I'm using windows 7 , and all what i want is to install Version Control server on one machine and let other developers to connect to it using the machine IP address and chekout, update and commit files

I have tried VisualSVN and it works well for me , I also have tried to install Apache Server and try to configure it to run with subversion but I failed to do so , so if any one can help me I will appreciated

Thanks in Advance

**Edit**

what I want if any one can suggest an alternative like VisualSVN that let me compare and choose from different options

Thanks in Advance

Comment: VisualSVN already comes with a bundled Apache internally. It takes away all the configuration woes, which is VisualSVN's point. Are you sure you need an external connection?

Comment: I just want another alternative to compare them and choose between them

Comment: You haven't said what your problem is and you haven't asked a question.

Comment: If VisualSVN works, then no other version of subversion is going to be that different.  Is the question that you want different types of version control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [CollabNet Subversion Edge](http://www.open.collab.net/products/subversion/) product bundle.  It has a lot of the administration and configuration issues made simple.  Bundles Subversion, Apache, ViewVC and their own administration/management tool for users and source repositories.  Works on multiple platforms (Windows, Linux, and Unix).  Also has a built in one click upgrade process that should make it easy to stay with the latest releases of Subversion and the other products that are bundled.

Comment: +1 on this. CollabNet Subversion Edge is a great way to get Subversion up and running on Windows servers.